# Installing Liferay 6.2 on IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5 with DB2 10.1

Tags: db2, websphere, liferay

A little help here. I need to install Liferay 6.2 with WebSphere Application Server 8.5 and DB2 10.1, so I followed the documentation guide for that installation type:

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/installing-liferay-on-websphere-8-5-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-15-en

But unfortunately, after doing all the steps in the installation guide, I was not still able to make Liferay work on WAS.

Even though I was able to run the liferay app, it still can't make the setup wizard show.

Comment: You probably need to provide more detail on what "didn't work" means. Error messages? Did you check log files?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Liferay 6.1 on DB2 9.7, and I got an error related to the tablespaces. Please, check the installation log file to see the DB2 error. But my problem was that it lacks of a 8KB tablespace

You need to create the database with a 8KB pagesize by default

```
db2 create db liferay pagesize 8 K
```

I wrote an article about that http://angocatech.blogspot.fr/2012/04/error-al-instalar-liferay-61-con-db2.html (In Spanish, ;) )

Answer (score 1):

If you followed litterally Liferay 6.2 installation guide you must enable wizard setting setup.wizard.enabled=true in portal-ext.properties

Comment: if this is explicitly set to false in portal-ext.properties, see if there is username specified in the file. for me it was username:test and password:test.

Answer (score 0):

Some more error logs would be great for debugging. 
However Liferay 6.2 should run in Websphere 8.5.X without any major issues:
http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/08/liferay-62-in-websphere-application.html

As an alternative you could try to setup an jdbc provider and a data source in websphere to connect to your db2 database. 
After that you could setup liferay to use the websphere data source by pointing it to the jndi name of the the data source.
portal-ext.properties:

```
##
## JDBC
##

    #
    # Set the JNDI name to lookup the JDBC data source. If none is set,
    # then the portal will attempt to create the JDBC data source based on the
    # properties prefixed with "jdbc.default.".
    #
    jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool
```

Comment out the other jdbc configurations.